# How can we draw a flowchart diagram in an react application?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

In an react application i need to draw flowcharts like below example .The diagram is drawing based on json data. Is there any npm packages or any java script library for solving this .

[image]

Comment: Asking for off-site resources (like libraries) is off-topic -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Ask on Software Recommendation ssite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use flowcharJS. flowchart.js is a flowchart DSL and SVG render that runs in the browser and terminal. You can draw a really complex chart with this

An example is [here](https://flowchart.js.org/)   and the library repo is [here](https://github.com/adrai/flowchart.js)

In a react app, use react-simple-flowchart which based on flowchart.js. The integration is straightforward

install through npm :

```
npm install react-simple-flowchart
```

And include in your project:

```
import Flowchart from 'react-simple-flowchart';
```

full documentation and usage information [here](https://github.com/alwinn1977/react-simple-flowchart)

There are couple of other libraries :

[Mermaid](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid)

[js-sequence-diagrams](https://github.com/bramp/js-sequence-diagrams)

Good Luck

Comment: Did you try anywhere ? I saw this before but difficult to integrate in react application

Comment: @SoorajJose I have edited my answer to point to react use case.

Comment: @SoorajJose what have you tried? at what point did you get confused?. if you can add this to your question, the community will have more information to help you.

Comment: its worked with react-simple-flowchart . [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-3hgb3) is example that i have tired